# Bootstrap set width on combined input fields without using the grid system

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to build some fields with combined input in Bootstrap. I was able to do so, but now I want to set the width of the input boxes.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group w-100">
  <span class="input-group-text w-20">Create</span>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Number of items" value =1/>
  <select class="form-control w-10" id="searchAssemblyType">
    <option>Item 1</option>
    <option>Item 2</option>
    <option>Both</option>
  </select>
  <input  class=" form-control w-70" type="text" id="partNumberInput" aria-describedby="enter Number" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search Items .." >
</div>
```

I tried to assign `w-100` to outer `<div>` and assigned w-something to inner items, but this does not seem to work. Is there a way to assign widths to these inputs without resorting to complex grids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use **[Bootstrap Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/)** to organize your layout, but if you still want to go with your solution using `width` relative to the parent. You can check the `width` & **`height`** **[utility classes docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/sizing/#relative-to-the-parent)**.

Basically, you were using the wrong **utility classes**. For **`width`**, **[Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)** offers five of them **`w-100`. `w-75`, `w-50`, `w-25` & `w-auto`**. So you should change your code to this snippet:

```
<div class="input-group w-100">
  <span class="input-group-text w-25">Create</span>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Number of items" value =1/>
  <select class="form-control w-25" id="searchAssemblyType">
    <option>Item 1</option>
    <option>Item 2</option>
    <option>Both</option>
  </select>
  <input  class=" form-control w-75" type="text" id="partNumberInput" aria-describedby="enter Number" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search Items .." >
</div>
```

Check this **[working code sample](https://jsfiddle.net/1hd34j8z/)**.

Another solution is to declare your own classes to each tag element & use custom CSS to give them **`width`** accordingly.